# Reactive Forms MinLength Validation Is Not Showing Error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I' using `ReactiveForms` in my Angular App. I want if user put less than 7 numbers so error message should be show there but unfortunately it's not working if there is any mistake or solution so please provide me.
Thanks

Service.ts

```
PhoneNo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7)]],
```

html

```
<input class="full-width has-padding has-border" formControlName="PhoneNo" type="tel" placeholder="Mobile *" />
        <img src="../../../../assets/img/required-img.png" class="required-img"
          *ngIf="service.formModel.get('PhoneNo').touched && service.formModel.get('PhoneNo').errors?.required"
          title="This fields is mandatory" data-toggle="tooltip" />
          <label *ngIf="service.formModel.get('PhoneNo').touched && service.formModel.get('PhoneNo').errors?.minLength">Minimum 7 characters required</label>
```

Comment: maybe not the cause of the problem but should be cleaned up as well: you are mixing up template- and reactive forms validation. there is a maxLength attribute on the input with a value of "7", you are having a minLength validator with a value of "7" and printing an error message stating that at least 9 characters are required...

Comment: share more code

Comment: @MarkusS. . yes there is a mistake in text of label but it should not be effected on my code. and also when I removed maxLenth it's not working.

Comment: @ShahidIslam which part you want to see?

Comment: form model declaration in service..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add maxLength validators , this will restrict the enter characters to 7 characters

```
PhoneNo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(7) , Validators.minLength(7)]],
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-array-controls-gn6trr)

Comment: but I want that user cannot enter less than 7 numbers.

Comment: you can add both min and max in that case , I have update the answer @WebMaster

Comment: @WebMaster I have include a live example

Answer (score 15):

This is well misleading from Angular side. Inside the component you set validators in the following way:

```
[Validators.minLength(2)]
```

Then, you would expect the following to work:

```
errors?.minLength
```

for whatever reason they decided to use the following format for error messages inside templates though:

```
errors?.minlength
```

The only thing you have to do is replace L with l

Comment: that's a bummer. Your answer definitely helped me,

Comment: Just to update you guys they still have not fixed this funny bug until now, I am using Angular 13.2.6. Thanks pete85 your answer saved me.

Answer (score 6):

Minimum 9 characters required

**user error key as minlength not minLength**

Answer (score 3):

You have maxLength as an attribute in your html. You should remove it

Instead of

```
<input class="full-width has-padding has-border" formControlName="PhoneNo" type="tel" placeholder="Mobile *" maxlength="7" />
```

Do this

```
<input class="full-width has-padding has-border" formControlName="PhoneNo" type="tel" placeholder="Mobile *">
```

Also, `<input>` and `<img>` should not have an enclosing tag at the end 
`<img/>` should be `<img>`

Instead of using minLength and maxLength together, you can create a regexp for it instead

```
PhoneNo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(^[\s\S]{7}$)]],
```

Also remember to use `service.formModel.get('PhoneNo').errors?.pattern` instead of `.errors?.minLength` in order to display the label.

**EDIT** 
@malbarmawi was kind enough to make a demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-pattern-bernj2. He also has another approach to solve the same problem himself.

Comment: @WebMaster did you check my answer ??

Comment: Did you add `Validators.pattern(^[\s\S]{7}$)` instead of maxLength?

Comment: yes but it show me error. "`The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`"

Comment: @John I have test you solution it's working so both of ours answer are correct 

Comment: The error related to arithmetic operations must be something else. Thanks to @malbarmawi for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it's not working - you should write `maxlength` in **lowercase**, **not camelcase**. same goes to `minlength`